# Повышение сложности зависящее от очков

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика

Такой вопрос:
Есть игра, космо-шутер, при уничтожении корабля игрок получает очки, когда очки переходят определенный порог, то срабатывает событие повышающие сложность игры. Нужно сделать, что бы каждые n очков(например каждую тысячу) повышалась сложность. С самим повышением сложности проблем нет. Просто нужно вызывать событие если очки кратны n. Но тут вопрос, как быть если, к примеру, у игрока 980 очков, каждую тысячу нужно увеличивать сложность, но при уничтожении корабля игрок получит 40 очков, то получится, что у игрока станет 1020 очков и событие не сработает, а надо бы, что бы сработало. Помогите решить данную проблему.

Comment: Проверяйте после добавления очков. 1040/1000 == Уровень

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте целочисленное деление.

Псевдокод:

```
level = points/1000 + 1;
```

При points = 980 уровень будет 0(=980/1000) + 1 = 1. При количестве очков 1020 уровень будет 1(=1020/1000) + 1 = 2, и т.д.

Но на самом деле вам надо проверять не кратность, а то, что количество очков превысило заданный уровень.